# Speeding up the following function

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, numpy, numba

I am implementing a code to find all the paths from top left to bottom right in a n*m matrix.

Here is my code:

```
# Python3 program to Print all possible paths from
# top left to bottom right of a mXn matrix

'''
/* mat: Pointer to the starting of mXn matrix
i, j: Current position of the robot 
    (For the first call use 0, 0)
m, n: Dimentions of given the matrix
pi: Next index to be filed in path array
*path[0..pi-1]: The path traversed by robot till now 
                (Array to hold the path need to have 
                space for at least m+n elements) */
'''
def printAllPathsUtil(mat, i, j, m, n, path, pi):

    # Reached the bottom of the matrix 
    # so we are left with only option to move right
    if (i == m - 1):
        for k in range(j, n):
            path[pi + k - j] = mat[i][k]

        for l in range(pi + n - j):
            print(path[l], end = " ")
        print()
        return

    # Reached the right corner of the matrix 
    # we are left with only the downward movement.
    if (j == n - 1):

        for k in range(i, m):
            path[pi + k - i] = mat[k][j]

        for l in range(pi + m - i):
            print(path[l], end = " ")
        print()
        return

    # Add the current cell 
    # to the path being generated
    path[pi] = mat[i][j]

    # Print all the paths 
    # that are possible after moving down
    printAllPathsUtil(mat, i + 1, j, m, n, path, pi + 1)

    # Print all the paths 
    # that are possible after moving right
    printAllPathsUtil(mat, i, j + 1, m, n, path, pi + 1)

    # Print all the paths 
    # that are possible after moving diagonal
    # printAllPathsUtil(mat, i+1, j+1, m, n, path, pi + 1);

# The main function that prints all paths 
# from top left to bottom right 
# in a matrix 'mat' of size mXn
def printAllPaths(mat, m, n):

    path = [0 for i in range(m + n)]
    printAllPathsUtil(mat, 0, 0, m, n, path, 0)



def printAllPaths(mat, m, n):
 
    path = [0 for i in range(m + n)]
    printAllPathsUtil(mat, 0, 0, m, n, path, 0)

matrix = np.random.rand(150, 150)
printAllPaths(matrix, 150, 150)
```

I would like to find all the paths for a 150 by 150 matrix. But this takes a lot of time. Is there a good way to make it faster? If there are also any suggestions to speed up the algorithm that would be great`.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question. Those two were something I had in mind but I would like to know the best way to speed up this process.

Comment: have you tried actually using numba or cython yet? As for the algorithm: you are basically calculating all permutations of m `move down`'s and n `move right`'s, so search for "generate all permutations" algorithms

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  You haven't shown any timing or profile data for your code -- where is it slow?  As posted this doesn't even run, as you never call your functions.

Comment: No I haven't. 

A* finds the path from top left to bottom right. But what I want is all the possible paths.

Comment: @TriposG I re-read your question more carefully and already edited my comment...

Comment: As the posting guidelines tell you, "Make it easy for others to help you".  We are not going to read through meaningless variable names to comment on your implementation.  Why have you chosen this style, rather than using any of the standard algorithms, already proved optimal for large graphs?

Comment: There are 93759702772827452793193754439064084879232655700081358920472352712975170021839591675861424 paths from top left to bottom right in a 150 by 150 matrix. No amount of optimization is going to allow you to enumerate them individually.

Comment: I haven't tried to follow your code, but in recursive iteration like this `numpy` does not have any benefits.  Iterating on a list, or list of lists, is faster.  In some cases it's even better to store the information in a dict.

Comment: This may be the kind of problem that someone on CodeReview would like to tackle, especially if it just uses Python lists (and not arrays).  But read the forum's requirements.  They tend to be picky(ier) about complete runnable code.

Comment: Given the ludicrously large number of possible paths for 150x150, I have to ask why you need to enumerate them all. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you talk of path a graph is a good solution, my idea is to build a graph with all paths and ask to him the solution, this print out all paths, each node is the couple of coordinates (x,y):

```
import networkx as nx
X = Y = 150

G = nx.DiGraph()
edges = []

for x in range(X):
    for y in range(Y):
        if x<X-1:
            edges.append(((x,y),(x+1,y)))
        if y<Y-1:
            edges.append(((x,y),(x,y+1)))
        
G.add_edges_from(edges)

print(len(G.nodes()))
print(len(G.edges()))

for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G,(0,0),(X-1,Y-1)):
  print(path)
```